# android 504 error

Tags: android

My application cannot be installed on devices with Android 7.1.1. Users can easily install other applications, but receive 504 error while installing mine. They tried to clear cache etc - nothing helps. The problem is on the application's side.

I had the same problem in the past (with Android 7.1.) which was fixed by changing compileSdkVersion from 23 to 25. But now I have no idea what I can change: both compileSdkVersion and even targetSdkVersion are set to the latest version available - 25.

This is my build.grandle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 91
        versionName "1.2.42"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by getting 504 error ?

Comment: `receive 504 error while installing mine`, Receive where?

Comment: users receive this error while trying to install my application on their devices

Comment: You mean while downloading it from PlayStore ?

Comment: yes, while downloading it from PlayStore

Comment: Clear cache and data for google play services. Did or not?

Comment: @dimabin 504 is connection timeout error code, i don't think it is your App problem !

Comment: The same problem was with Android 7.1. It was impossible to install my application on devices with Android 7.1. Clearing cache and other methods described on various sites did not help. Only after changing compileSdkVersion from 23 to 25 it was possible to install my application on Android 7.1. But now users have exactly the same problem with Android 7.1.1. And now I don't know what I can do